# performance of installing MAC os with xcode in Windows

Tags: xcode, windows, virtualbox

If i am installing mac for xcode (Create Native iOS Application) in windows,

Can i developed standard iOS application(beginning to end)?
Is it a viable option to develop in window through virtual box.
My system has ram of 16gb, intel i5 8th gen processor, quad core.
can i integrated third party library while developing apps?

I have no idea about Speed, performance, lifetime. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can install mac os for xcode (Create Native iOS Application) in windows by using virtual box.**

**Yes you can develope standard iOS application(beginning to end).**

If you have no any other mac resource then it is ok for develop in window through virtual box. But i suggest use mac for better experiance and performance.

Comment: Thanks for response sir.  my laptop only for development purpose. what about performance speed using virtual box.

Comment: @VigneshJ Initially it works smoothly but after large data it's lagging in performance.

Comment: If i am using xcode in virtual box. is faster during using xcode and simulator?

Comment: Not that much faster but at least you can do your work. Something is better than nothing !!!

Comment: how can i maintain speed of xcode. If i am using virtual box, What are the problems are occurred in laptop?

Comment: Ohh yes sir. Thank for your response sir.

Comment: Welcome @VigneshJ